# Ignore specific comma in timestamp using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql, csv, import, load-data-infile

I've got a ton of CSV files that are all formated as such:

```
    2015/06/29,13:00,1,194,36,390
```

As you can probably see i need to ignore the comma that separates the "2015/06/29" and the "13:00" in the above example.

Currenly this is what my sql command looks like:

```
    LOAD DATA local INFILE '"!new!"' IGNORE into table db.table COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 3 LINES (@when,col2,col3,col4,col5) SET when=STR_TO_DATE(@when,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i')" -u user -ppass
```

Everything imports with the exception of that pesky comma throwing everything off by one column.

Obviously I could import both into separate columns, but they all need to go into one DATETIME formatted column.  Anybody have any idea how I would jump through that hoop?

Comment: you can't. there's no way to tell mysql "this is a separator comma", and "this is some garbage that LOOKS like a comma, ignore it". it's all just commas. import to a temp table with an extra field for your two date/time components, then do a select into the permanent table, combining those two values. Then go beat up who/whatever produced that faulty csv.

Comment: Or, load the first two fields into two separate user-defined variables, and use `CONCAT()` function to combine them. Then run the return from that through the `STR_TO_DATE`, just like you are already doing. (I'm not sure why this question received a downvote.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "ignore" the comma. Just import the two fields into two separate user-defined variables, and then concatenate those into a single value for the column.

Put the date portion into a user-defined variable, just like you are already doing: `@whendt`

Put put the second field, the time portion, into a *second* user-defined variable: `@whentm`

In the `SET` clause, concatenate those two variables together with the `CONCAT` function.

```
  CONCAT(@whendt, ' ', @whentm)
```

For example:

```
 LOAD DATA local INFILE '"!new!"' 
 IGNORE 
 INTO table db.table 
 COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 IGNORE 3 LINES 
 ( @whendt    -- first column is date portion
 , @whentm    -- second column is time portion
 , col2
 , col3
 , col4
 , col5 
 )
 SET when = STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(@whendt,' ',@whentm) ,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i')
```

Comment: Damn!  I never would have thought of that.  You're awesome spencer!

Comment: @JubJub24: You already had the assignment to the user-defined variable and the functions in the SET clause already figured out. You were already there. I think you were just hung up on the "ignore the comma" idea. Marc B and tadman are both right... there's no way to get LOAD DATA to ignore that second comma. They are absolutely right about that. The trick to getting LOAD DATA to work with this file is to work *with* the comma, not *against* it.

Comment: That's some pretty Zen stuff.  I will be one with the comma :)

Comment: I've got `LOAD DATA` statements that put *every* field into user-defined variables. I use variable named `@dummy` for the fields I want to ignore. And I can build some frighteningly *horrendous* expressions in the `SET` clause, conditional tests, concatenation, replacing pesky dollar sign characters, replacing empty strings with NULL, et al. User-defined variables and building expressions is where the Zen is. (You were *already* Zen.)